# Angular Material components are displayed without padding

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I've created an Angular (12) project, added Material with "indigo-pink" theme and created a form. But all form components are rendered without any horizontal white space between each other. For testing purposes I copied a code snippet with [Buttons from the Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) website:

```
  <section>
    <div class="example-label">Raised</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
      <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
      <button mat-raised-button disabled>Disabled</button>
      <a mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

They are rendered like this in my application:

[image]

But they should be rendered like on the Angular Material website:

[image]

The style sheets seems to be imported correctly in `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

Other global (or local) styles were not added or modified.

How can I fix the margin?

Comment: I am getting exact same problem. Did you ever able to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this style to your component

```
.mat-button-base {
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 0;
}
```

It probably misses from the imported theme `indigo-pink.css`

Comment: Thanks, but it looks the same with this style.

Comment: @daemon I created an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ss8res . When you remove the code I posted above the padding is eliminated. When you add it, padding is correct. Check it. Somehow your css that you added with my answer is not correctly applied

Comment: You're right: The style sheet wasn't applied. I had put it into `src/styles.css`, but that didn't work for some reason. After putting the CSS into the component CSS file, it looks like it should. However, as far as I know margins should be correct out of the box with Angular Material and I fear that there is some more fundamental problem. Other form elements are also rendered without spacing between them.

Answer (score 2):

Solution of @Panagiotis Bougioukos works fine.
It shoud work for you, but, if for any reason it doesn't work,try this:

```
.buttonflex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Raised</div>
    <div class="example-button-row buttonflex">
      <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
      <button mat-raised-button disabled>Disabled</button>
      <a mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </div>
  </section>
```